# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre HTML y SHTML?

Tags: html

He observado que hay varias páginas en Colombia que tienen la extensión `.shtml`, sin embargo no sé qué función especial tiene, hasta el momento solo sabía que había `html`.

Answer (score 6):

Los archivos con extensión `.shtml` son archivos que le permiten al servidor saber que archivo debe ser procesado junto con [***Server Side Includes (SSI)***](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Esto permite tener un archivo e incluirlo a través de otros para no redundar tanto código y hacerlo de una manera recursiva, es algo más o menos así:

```
<!--#include virtual="top.shtml" -->
```

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519619/what-is-shtml)(*enlace en inglés*) hay más información al respecto

Answer (score 3):

Aquí hay un error **muy común**: confundir **la extensión** con **la función**.

En el caso de la pregunta, **por convención**, se **suele** utilizar la extensión indicada para lo explicado en las otras respuestas: permitir identificar dicho archivo como *usuario* de la funcionalidad *serve side includes*.

**Pero ...** eso **no tiene porqué ser así**.

En última instancia, desde el lado del cliente, el archivo se identifica por el tipo `MIME` del mismo; dicho tipo es enviado junto al archivo en la respuesta. En el caso indicado, ese tipo `MIME` indicaría `text/html`, lo cual permite a nuestro cliente (navegador, cliente de consola, ... ) **saber** como ha de interpretarlo.

Desde el lado del *servidor* ... la cosa cambia. Dependiendo del mismo, se puede configurar de una u otra forma para que realice distintas acciones ante distintas **extensiones** de archivo.

Por ejemplo, en los archivos indicados, **es perfectamente posible** que se procesen mediante PHP, y se use esa extensión para *despistar*. La conocida como técnica de *ocultación*, para *dificultar* la búsqueda de vulnerabilidades por posibles *crackers*.

Resumiendo: sin mas datos, **no podemos saber** lo que implica **exactamente** la extensión `.shtml`.

**Si** es cierto que, por **convención** y **contumbre**, dicha extensión se usa como indican en las otras respuestas, **pero no hay garantía de ello**.

Answer (score 1):

Segun he entendido es un model en el cual puede incluir instrucciones que se van a ejecutar del lado del servidor y es una nueva implementación del algun tipo de lenguaje nativo de HTML. Segun esto entendi.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Answer (score 0):

[HTML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) es una página estática a diferencia de SHTML que por medio de [SSI (server sides includes)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) puede realizar algun tipo de proceso en el servidor.

Un archivo html habilitado para SSI, SHTML puede tener otras extensiones como son :

- .shtml
- .stm
- .shtm
- Aunque también es posible configurar un .html en el server para que funcione con SSI.

Ejemplo html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Hola Stackoverflow.com
</body>
</html>
```

Ejemplo shtml donde al cargar la página obtiene el contenido de `mymenu.html` mediante `<!--#include file="mymenu.html" -->`:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!--#include file="mymenu.html" -->
Hola Stackoverflow.com
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. SHTML

SHTML es una extensión de archivo que se utiliza para la inclusión de archivos HTML del lado del servidor. Podríamos decir que es una variante de HTML. (ver punto 2)

Es lo que se conoce como Server Side Includes (SSI).

[Según Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html):

> SSI (Server Side Includes) son directivas que se colocan en páginas
>   HTML y se evalúan en el servidor mientras se están publicando las
>   páginas. Le permiten agregar contenido generado dinámicamente a una
>   página HTML existente, sin tener que servir toda la página a través de
>   un programa CGI u otra tecnología dinámica.

Por ejemplo, se puede colocar una directiva en una página HTML existente de la siguiente manera:

```
<! - # echo var = "DATE_LOCAL" ->
```

Y, cuando se sirve la página, este fragmento será evaluado y reemplazado por su valor:

```
Martes, 15-ene-2013 19:28:54 EST
```

La decisión de cuándo usar SSI y cuándo tener la página generada por algún programa, suele ser una cuestión de cuánto de la página es estática y cuánto necesita ser recalculada cada vez que se sirve la página. SSI es una excelente manera de agregar pequeños fragmentos de información, como la hora actual - mostrada arriba. Pero si una mayoría de su página se está generando en el momento en que se sirve, usted necesita buscar alguna otra solución.

Con SSI se pueden hacer cosas un poco más avanzadas como manejar variables, escribir código en bloques lógicos (usando condicionales), y otras. Al menos en Apache debe estar activada para que funcione.

La conclusión de Apache al respecto es la siguiente (ver documentación, cuyo enlace ha sido indicado más arriba):

> SSI no es ciertamente un reemplazo para CGI u otras tecnologías usadas
>   para generar páginas web dinámicas. Pero es una gran manera de agregar
>   pequeñas cantidades de contenido dinámico a las páginas, sin hacer
>   mucho trabajo extra.

### 2. Algunos datos interesantes sobre SHTML

#### ¿Quién inventó SHTML y cómo se define?

Según [filext.com](http://filext.com/file-extension/SHTML) la extensión fue creada por Microsoft Corporation. Y dan la siguiente información detallada para la extensión de archivo SHTML:

```
Asociación primaria: Archivo HTML que contiene Directivas del lado del servidor
Compañía: Microsoft Corporation
Mime type: wwwserver/html-ssi, text/html
```

[Programas que pueden abrir archivos con extension SHTML](http://extension.nirsoft.net/shtml)

#### ¿Es muy usado hoy día?

Por curiosidad hice una búsqueda en Google poniendo:

```
a filetype:shtml
```

y... la verdad que me quedé sorprendido. Si alquien quiere comprobarlo, adelante :)

### 3. HTML

Bueno, ya a ese lo conocemos. Simplemente recordar [la definición que hace de él MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML):

> HTML significa Lenguaje de Marcado para Hipertextos (HyperText Markup
>   Language). Es el elemento de construcción más básico de una página web
>   y se usa para crear y representar visualmente una página web.
>   Determina el contenido de la página web, pero no su funcionalidad.
>   Otras tecnologías distintas de HTML son usadas generalmente para
>   describir la apariencia/presentación de una página web (CSS) o su
>   funcionalidad (JavaScript).
>
> HTML usa "markup" o marcado para anotar textos, imágenes, y otros
>   contenidos que se muestran en el Navegador Web. El lenguaje de marcado
>   HTML incluye "elementos" especiales tales como `<head>, <title>,
>   <body>, <header>, <article>, <section>, <p>, <div>, <span>, <img>`, y
>   muchos otros más.

Desde 1996, el World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) ha mantenido las especificaciones HTML con el aporte de proveedores de software comerciales. Sin embargo, en 2000, el HTML también se convirtió en un estándar internacional (ISO / IEC 15445: 2000). El hito más reciente es HTML5, aún mejorado hasta la especificación completa publicad en 2014.

[filext.com](http://filext.com/file-extension/HTML) da la siguiente información detallada para la extensión de archivo HTML:

```
Asociación primaria: 
Primary association: Hypertext Markup Language
Mime type: text/html, text/plain
```